# pip can't find flit-core dependency when offline installing other packages

Tags: python, linux, pip, package

So i'm trying to install idna and trio, and both need flit_core, the problem is that I'm installing it in an offline machine downloading from this PyPi resource "https://pypi.org/project/flit-core/", it install it perfectly, but when I try to install the other two, it says:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flit_core<4,>=3.9.0 (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for flit_core<4,>=3.9.0

I've been installing the 3.9.0 version and that one should work, but it does not find it.

Does anyone know what could be happening? thanks!

EDIT.

I've tried several versions of flit-core with no luck, neither 3.9.0, nor 3.8.0. It does not recognize flit_core when installing flit and/or idna3.4.

I've checked site-packages inside the python3.11 version and there are the folders flit_core and flit_core..dist-info.

Comment: Hi @Varox, I'm facing the same issue here, may I ask how did you solve this?

Comment: I have this same issue as well - flit_core is installed and I have the right version, but during the dependent package setup it fails saying it can't find flt_core, same message as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `--no-build-isolation` as part of your install command.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check compatibility of the version of idna3.4 you are trying to install with your installed python version rather than compatibility of flit-core.

Search for history versions of idna until you find the correct one.

I had the same issue while trying to install blinker-1.7.0 and having an issue with flit-core dependancy.
I then tried to install blinker-1.6 and had an issue with setuptools.
Finally I tried blinker-1.5 and it worked.